# Valor con mayor ocurrencias en columna

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente dataframe obtenido de

http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv

```
head(df)

##   Year     City      Sport     Discipline NOC           Event Event.gender  Medal
## 1 1924 Chamonix    Skating Figure skating AUT      individual            M Silver
## 2 1924 Chamonix    Skating Figure skating AUT      individual            W   Gold
## 3 1924 Chamonix    Skating Figure skating AUT           pairs            X   Gold
## 4 1924 Chamonix  Bobsleigh      Bobsleigh BEL        four-man            M Bronze
## 5 1924 Chamonix Ice Hockey     Ice Hockey CAN      ice hockey            M   Gold
## 6 1924 Chamonix   Biathlon       Biathlon FIN military patrol            M Silver
```

Puedo saber cuantos deportistas participaron cada año de la siguiente manera

```
table(df$Year)

## 
## 1924 1928 1932 1936 1948 1952 1956 1960 1964 1968 1972 1976 1980 1984 1988 1992 
##   49   41   42   51   68   67   72   81  103  106  105  111  115  117  138  171 
## 1994 1998 2002 2006 
##  183  205  234  252
```

El año 2006 fue el año con más participantes, pero ¿cúal sería el código para obtener el año con más participantes?

La respuesta sería

```
2006
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En términos estadísticos lo que buscas es la moda, el valor que más veces se repite.

De forma simple:

```
tabla <- table(df$Year)
names(tabla[tabla == max(tabla)])
```

La última función te regresa el atributo `names()` (el nombre) en la tabla cuando el valor en esa tabla es igual al máximo en esa tabla.